# Can't access nuxt-i18n info

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am working on an international blog in nuxt. I cant seem to access the i18n object in the nav component and on some pages. Can you clarify how to access it and why I cant? I am assuming it is lifecycle related but not sure...

In nuxt-config.js:

```
...
  modules: [
    'nuxt-i18n',
    '@nuxt/content'
  ],
  i18n:{
    strategy: 'prefix_and_default',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    langDir: 'lang/',
    lazy: true,
    locales: [
      {
        name: '日本語',
        code: 'ja',
        iso: 'ja-JP',
        file: 'ja-JP.js'
      },
      {
        name: 'English',
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        file: 'en-US.js'
      },
    ],
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      // If enabled, a cookie is set once a user has been redirected to his
      // preferred language to prevent subsequent redirections
      // Set to false to redirect every time
      useCookie: true,
      // Set to override the default domain of the cookie. Defaults to host of the site.
      cookieDomain: null,
      // Cookie name
      cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
      // Set to always redirect to value stored in the cookie, not just once
      alwaysRedirect: false,
      // If no locale for the browsers locale is a match, use this one as a fallback
    }
  },
...
```

I am trying to bring in different markdown files depending on the language so I am calling:

```
export default {
    async asyncData({ $content, params}) {
      const data = await $content(`${i18n.locale}/data`, params.slug).fetch()
      return { data }
    },
```

in content I have `en/data/...` and `ja/data/...` and it works if I hard code it as `en/data/` or `ja/data` but I get i18n is undefined errors, I have tried several patterns but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use this structure in your code

https://nuxtjs.org/examples/i18n/